# Python - Passing a number as a parameter to filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example i have two files .txt.
First file has 78 lines, second file has 30 lines.
Is there any easy way to pass a number as a parameter to the result?
Currently in result I get:

```
first_file_20.txt
first_file_40.txt
first_file_60.txt
first_file_80.txt
second_file_20.txt
second_file_40.txt
```

but I would like to have as a result:

```
first_file_1.txt
first_file_2.txt
first_file_3.txt
first_file_4.txt
second_file_1.txt
second_file_2.txt
```

code:

```
import re
import os

lines_per_file = 20
smallfile = None

root_path = os.getcwd()

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path,name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path,name))
    print(files) #list all files in directory

    for ii in files:
        if ii.endswith(".txt"): # only txt files
            with open(ii,'r') as bigfile:
                name1 = str(os.path.basename(ii).split(".")[0])
                name2 = str(name1 + '_{}.txt')
                #
                print('name', name2)
                for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
                    w = 1
                    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                        if smallfile:
                            smallfile.close()
                        small_filename = name2.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
                        smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
                    smallfile.write(line)
                if smallfile:
                    smallfile.close()
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why is the amount of lines in the file relevant here?

Comment: Are you trying to rename the files? Is this just for display purposes? Do you know if the file names that you want to iterate will always have the same prefix?

Comment: Filenames will always have the same prefix

Comment: I want to divide large files into smaller ones so that I can process them later with regular expressions

Comment: So all the `first_file_N.txt` are chunks of `first_file.txt`? You know you can do this with the Unix `split` command, don't you?

Comment: And you can use `os.path.splitext()` to separate the filename and extension.

Comment: @Barmar - yes, all the first_file_N.txt are chunks of first_file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add `lineno` and `lines_per_file`, divide them.

```
small_filename = name2.format(lineno//lines_per_file + 1)
```